# Can I reboot during a btrfs replace and then resume it?

Tags: btrfs, replace

I have a damaged hard disk with a lot of read errors. I'm currently doing a btrfs replace, but after 24 hours at just over 5% done, this is a problem: it's my work computer; I'm currently booted onto a Live USB, but I need to go back to the existing Ubuntu to continue my work (it has a really hard time booting in with all the read errors, but is able to make it sometimes).

Note: the entire hard disk, or at least this partition of it, curently reads at ~500 KBps, even when there aren't read errors - the `btrfs replace status` currently reports 0 read errors.

So I have two options:
1) just shut down, reboot into the other OS, and try to run the same `btrfs replace start` command I first ran.
2) cancel the current replace operation, which may take forever (I already tried a cancel before, a minute into the replace, and it seemed to take just as long to cancel) and would undo a day's hard-earned transfer progress.
3) admit defeat and just settle into this LiveUSB OS for the next 2-3 weeks and pray that the cleaning people don't bump the USB stick.

Comment: To address the slow speed of `replace`, see [btrfs replace on RAID1 is super slow with failed disk present](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/496777/143394)

Answer (score 3):

Reviving this question because it's the top Google result when searching for "btrfs replace resume" and the existing answer doesn't tell the whole story.

The replace process automatically resumes after a reboot (much like a balance). I've even had to do a hard-reset during a replace operation and the process happily continued after rebooting and remounting the filesystem. So my guess is that it wasn't the interrupted replace operation itself that gave sssheridan all these problems, but rather the circumstances of having to boot from a dying harddisk.

When mounting after an interrupted replace, a log-line like this is printed:

```
BTRFS info (device sdh1): continuing dev_replace from /dev/sdb1 (devid 5) to target /dev/sdh1 @95%
```

The last number is the completion percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my question: I tried it, and everything is on fire. Input/output errors everywhere and somehow my filesystem thinks it's RAID1 when it's not. To be fair, a partition was already corrupt and that seems to be part of the problem, but nevertheless I Do Not Recommend doing this. Do a `btrfs replace cancel` and wait it out.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR:

Yes. But run `scrub` afterwards.

#### The long version:

[This LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/524589/) gives the commit text for `replace` and says:

> It is safe to crash or lose power during the operation, the
>   process resumes with the next mount.

I rebooted with my `replace` at about 5% complete because [btrfs replace on RAID1 was super slow with the failed disk present](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/496777/143394).

After `replace` resumed and completed, I noticed that `btrfs device usage /mountpoint` was showing some `Data,DUP` and `Metadata,single`, rather than only `RAID1`. This was likely due to `btrfs` writing `DUP` as it couldn't write a 2nd copy to the failed drive. I rebalanced to make everything RAID1:

```
btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1,soft -mconvert=raid1,soft /mountpoint
```

Now all data was showing as `RAID1`, I thought I'd just check all was ok:

```
btrfs scrub start -Bd /mountpoint
```

I'm glad I did, as I'm got lots of `csum errors` at about 151GiB scrubbed on `id 2` (the newly replaced device):

```
scrub device /dev/mapper/vg4TBd3-ark (id 1) status
        scrub started at Mon Jan 28 20:47:33 2019, running for 00:41:40
        total bytes scrubbed: 153.53GiB with 0 errors
scrub device /dev/mapper/vg6TBd1-ark (id 2) status
        scrub started at Mon Jan 28 20:47:33 2019, running for 00:41:40
        total bytes scrubbed: 151.49GiB with 174840 errors
        error details: csum=174840
        corrected errors: 174837, uncorrectable errors: 0, unverified errors: 0
```

`scrub` was crawling at this point. The logs showed many lines like:

```
BTRFS warning (device dm-5): checksum error at logical 3425803567104 on dev /dev/mapper/vg6TBd1-ark, physical 162136981504, root 5, inode 3367374, offset 0, length 4096, links 1 (path: HDDs/Quantum LM30/Linux1/home/tn/uts.old/etc/root/home/tn/build/linux-2.4.13-ac8/linux/include/net/sock.h)
BTRFS error (device dm-5): bdev /dev/mapper/vg6TBd1-ark errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 1, gen 0                                                                               
BTRFS error (device dm-5): fixed up error at logical 3425803567104 on dev /dev/mapper/vg6TBd1-ark                                                                                 
scrub_handle_errored_block: 806 callbacks suppressed
```

I ended up with a total of 262016 corrected errors, when I next checked at 184GiB scrubbed (it was zooming along again happily at this point).

I didn't receive a single error after that, meaning that all the errors were concentrated about the 151GiB point.

151GiB is roughly 5% of my total 2.88TiB, the point at which I restarted.

Perhaps it was just co-incidence, but I'm glad I ran `scrub` regardless.